# Windows 10 start menu undeletable WPS Office folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu, regedit

I recently bought a new Windows PC which came with pre-installed software.

I deleted everything apart from the app [WPS Office](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH42WS3), because at first I  could not uninstall. Afterwards, using [Windows App Boss](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=windowsappboss) I managed to delete [WPS Office](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH42WS3).

But in start menu there's still the [WPS Office](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH42WS3) folder, empty, with a blue square icon (instead of the classic folder icon), so apparently "bugged", but being able to right-click to open its Microsoft app page and other stuff:

[image: Screen Shot]

So I opened regedit (I am not very good with Windows PC, so at that point I was just trying without knowing exactly what I was doing) and deleted every single reference to [WPS Office](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH42WS3) and Zhuhai-Kingsoft (which appears to be the name of the developers)

Previously, I scanned through C: drive (partition) for those keywords and then deleted everything. After a system restart, there were no tangible trace of [WPS Office](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH42WS3) if not in the start menu, still here as always. I really don't know what to do to get rid of that. Also, I obviously searched for all appdata roaming/local subfolders, where I usually find start menu folders.

Comment: For future reference, rather than devoting a lot of time and effort toward removing individual applications on a new Windows 10 computer, it would probably be much easier to [utilize the built-in Fresh Start](https://superuser.com/questions/1293547/reset-windows-10-on-new-computer-to-remove-bloatware/1293656#1293656) function.

Comment: Well, actually i didn't delete all pre-installed apps, since some were useful. Thus even a fresh start wouldn't have been effortless. Of course, at the time i would have never imagined that this app would cause so much trouble, and by now a fresh restart would still mean a lot of work.TL;DR i just wanted to delete 5 or 6 apps and i discorvered too late that one was still here

Answer (score 1):

Items in the Start Menu for Windows 10 are collected from several places, but one you haven't mentioned is the actual Start Menu folder.

The way to find this is to **right-click** on another entry in your Start Menu, select **More**, and then **Open File Location**.

*If the icon you clicked does not have Open File Location, try another one.*

This will likely open `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\...`

Navigate around here and see if you find the annoying **WPS Office** folder. You may need to be local admin to delete the folder if you find it.

Comment: Sadly, i tried to be as brief  as i could in my question, and did not mention this route, which was one of the first i took, still with no success