# How do I reinstall Internet Explorer on Windows 10 if the 'feature name is unknown'

Tags: windows-10, powershell, internet-explorer-11, windows-10-v1709

I have previously uninstalled Internet Explorer on Windows 10. When I attempt to reinstall using the following PowerShell commands

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Select FeatureName | Select-String Internet*
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64 –Online
```

I get the following error

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Feature name Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64 is unknown.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Internet-Explorer-Optional ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

There is also no option to re-enable it in 'Turn Windows features on or off'.

How can I resolve this error so that Windows 10 can reinstall Internet Explorer?

Comment: You didn't simply turn off the Windows feature?  If that's the case and you really want Internet Explorer back again, it may be necessary to perform a [Fresh Start](https://superuser.com/questions/1293547/reset-windows-10-on-new-computer-to-remove-bloatware/1293656#1293656) install of the operating system.  Obviously that involves quite a bit more time and effort, but it will definitely get the job done.

Comment: How did you remove it.  Edit your question.  It’s possible you removed the package, if that’s the case, you will have to mount an ISO in order to install it again.  Of course error indicates the package name is also incorrect

Comment: I removed it using the 'Turn Windows features on or off' menu, but that was in a previous Windows 10 feature update. The package name seems to be correct as the command works fine on another machine.

Comment: If you remove it from "Turn Windows feature on or off" panel, it will appear there after restart.

Comment: I removed it from the computer some time ago, and the option has been absent for a while across many reboots.