# Full reinstall of Windows 10 that came with laptop?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, performance, reinstall

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad laptop that came with Windows 10.

It has 4 Gb RAM, which was plenty just a few years ago. But on this machine Windows 10 was pretty slow to start with. Adding a 16Gb flash drive dedicated to ReadyBoost helped matters somewhat.

But now, after half a year of use, it became very slow even with ReadyBoost - so slow even YouTube videos can stutter. I did install Avast which does not detect anything, so I don't think it's malware. It is probably the usual "Windows rot", which I am familiar with since Windows 9x and which requires a fresh reinstall. Yes, half a year is a bit too soon - Windows tended to last over a year until it rotted like that. Perhaps it's those huge updates...

Anyway - HOW can I do that fresh reinstall thing if no installation media came with the device?

An alternative would be installing Windows 7 and I even have some OEM packs, but I'm not sure I can find Windows 7 drivers for everything on the machine, including the touch screen, etc. Also, I wonder if Windows 7 will keep working in "tablet mode" which this thing has.

(Another alternative is Linux and it is seriously being considered but I am asking here so I can look at WIndows options. Also not sure about "tablet mode" on Linux).

Comment: I would strongly recommend utilizing the built-in [Fresh Install](https://superuser.com/questions/1293547/reset-windows-10-on-new-computer-to-remove-bloatware/1293656#1293656) function as a much easier alternative to a "full reinstall."  It will essentially achieve the same results while saving you a great deal of time and effort.

Comment: “Windows rot” isn’t a real thing.  If your machine is slow, then you have installed software, that has caused the slowness.  I have had the same installation of Windows for 7 years.  I have upgraded that machine from Windows 7 to Windows 8 to Windows 10 1509 plus all other feature updates and also migrated the installation to other devices l.  It’s still as fast as the day I installed it.

Comment: Reinstalling Windows 10 is as simple as downloading the current Windows 10 ISO and installing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a fresh installation of Windows 10 with [Windows Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO). You can then use [Lenovo System Update](https://support.lenovo.com/no/en/downloads/ds012808) to get the drivers.

It would probably be easier for you to just use ["Windows 10 reset this PC](https://www.google.no/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/132428/everything-you-need-to-know-about-refreshing-and-resetting-your-windows-8-pc/amp/)" which is the same as a clean install if you choose not to keep any files.

Remember to do a backup first if you want to keep any files.