# How to reset user permissions on system files and registry keys to the state when Windows was installed?

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, windows-registry, icacls

I currently have Windows 10 Pro version 1803 (build 17134.254) installed.

Thing is, I did some stuff to user permissions on some files and registry keys and I believe I might have also affected some system related stuff as well since most stuff such as Cortana and the start menu literally speaking won't launch anymore. How to undo all this without the knowledge of which system files got affected? And may I add one more thing: I tried creating multiple user accounts(Admin and Standard) and they both weren't able to render icons(any icon - anything that can be found both in shell32.dll and imageres.dll).

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  We are always glad to help, but it would really help if you told us [which version of Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/236195/how-to-find-out-which-build-and-version-of-windows-10-you-have/) you are utilizing.

Comment: I have Windows 10 Pro 1803 17134.254 currently installed.

Comment: Based upon what you have described, it would probably be wise to use the [Windows 10 Fresh Start](https://superuser.com/a/1293656/650163) function to restore your operating system to a stable configuration.

Comment: To elaborate just a bit more, there isn't anything inherently wrong with changing permissions related to files and folders.  The registry can be very tricky in that regard, and I would be much more hesitant to do that.  But all things considered, you should always ensure that you have a comprehensive backup before making significant changes.  By any chance, do you have a [System Restore](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4588-system-restore-windows-10-a.html) point that was taken prior to any of the changes you made?  If not, the Fresh Start is probably your best course of action.