# I want to reset my windows. What would be my best option?

Tags: reset

My Windows is installed by a friend. I am afraid that he may put keylogger there. Very small chance.

[image]

There are 2 options.

Delete all files or keep all files.

Well, all files on the system drive is redundant. Most data is in cloud. I don't care.

If I decide to delete all files will it delete only system drive or all of the drives?

Also which one will address my concern?

Comment: They both will address your concern.  The only question, which is a question only you can answer if you want to delete your personal files.  The process of performing a Reset will be identical.  Windows will temporarily reinstall Windows, it will move the old installation into a folder within that installation of Windows, the only difference is if your user profiles will or won't be transfered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Windows know which files to keep during reset](https://superuser.com/questions/1156769/how-does-windows-know-which-files-to-keep-during-reset)

Comment: Not explicitly. It seems that in any case only the file in the user directory that is preserved. The rest stay fine. The problem is the answer talk about reset vs refresh. I am not even sure which one is which

Comment: [I have already explained the difference between Reset and Refresh](https://superuser.com/questions/1151465/will-doing-a-full-reset-remove-everything-of-windows-10-be-same-as-formatting/1151479#1151479).  Microsoft changed the name of the feature when 2004 was released.  My existing explanation still explains the process that Reset will use. The only difference between now and then is that Refresh was a separate option. Now regardless (If I am not mistaken) an image is downloaded and that is used to reinstall Windows.

Comment: If a really persistent keylogger has been installed, perhaps a rootkit, reinstalling Windows might *not* remove it. And some key loggers are *hardware*, installed inside the PC. So is the trouble of reinstalling Windows worthwhile?